# How to convert camera image to image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert camera image from function `startImageStream` of camera plugin in Flutter to Image to crop that image but I only find the way to convert to FirebaseVisionImage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit For Color Image**

if I understand you clear. You are trying to covnert YUV420 format. The following is code snippet from: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348

```dart
const shift = (0xFF << 24);
Future<Image> convertYUV420toImageColor(CameraImage image) async {
  try {
    final int width = image.width;
    final int height = image.height;
    final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
    final int uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel;

    print("uvRowStride: " + uvRowStride.toString());
    print("uvPixelStride: " + uvPixelStride.toString());

    // imgLib -> Image package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image
    var img = imglib.Image(width, height); // Create Image buffer

    // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        final int uvIndex = uvPixelStride * (x / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (y / 2).floor();
        final int index = y * width + x;

        final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
        final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
        final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
        // Calculate pixel color
        int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
        int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91).round().clamp(0, 255);
        int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);
        // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF
        //           A   B   G   R
        img.data[index] = shift | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
      }
    }

    imglib.PngEncoder pngEncoder = new imglib.PngEncoder(level: 0, filter: 0);
    List<int> png = pngEncoder.encodeImage(img);
    muteYUVProcessing = false;
    return Image.memory(png);
  } catch (e) {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR:" + e.toString());
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sir. Its great

Comment: hi sir. have you tried this convert function yet? I try to display the image after convert but the new image don't have color

Comment: I have updated my answer. Could you test it again? and let me know result . thank you very much. I will delete this answer if it not work well.

Comment: Yeah i have checked the link you give me and changed to color before, it worked well. By the way, because this function run very slow depend on the loop, I set (0xFF << 24) as a constant and set it as a parameter of the function every time I call. Its kinda faster about 5 times. Thanks for helps @chunhunghan. Are you vietnamese?

Comment: Glad to help. No I am not. thank you for your time. It might have green screen so reported. but I do not have real device to test it.

Comment: Hi @chunhunghan, do you know other way to do this? feel like this method make the memory of flutter app increase time after time then crash, it's not good

Comment: Would like to try this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348#issuecomment-537826541 , gist is here https://gist.github.com/Alby-o/fe87e35bc21d534c8220aed7df028e03

Comment: Amazing, this method is faster then before, thanks you. However, the memory is still keep growing, it's weird

Comment: I would suggest ask gist owner does he also encounter memory leak issue.

Comment: Feel like this method is the same with above method, my CameraImage format is not bgra8888, so it faster but cannot regconize face

Comment: I realized that the issue make memory growing came from Isolate in flutter. Do you have any idea? I have a post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58589261/is-there-memory-issue-with-isolate-in-flutter-app

Comment: not working in ios `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1` because `bytesPerPixel` is null and `image.planes.length = 1` in IOS. 
Is there any other way? Please help me.

Comment: planes[0] also has bytes per row, so final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index] should be final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[y * plan0bytesperrow * x]

Comment: muteYUVProcessing = false;  <- this seems to be a random /unused variable 

   return Image.memory(png);  <error  argument type 'List<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Answer (score 3):

Here is the iOS implementation:

```
const IOS_BYTES_OFFSET = 28;

static Image _convertBGRA8888ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
  final plane = cameraImage.planes[0];

  return Image.fromBytes(
    width: cameraImage.width,
    height: cameraImage.height,
    bytes: plane.bytes.buffer,
    rowStride: plane.bytesPerRow,
    bytesOffset: IOS_BYTES_OFFSET,
    order: ChannelOrder.bgra,
  );
}
```

I figured out `IOS_BYTES_OFFSET` by trial and error.. but it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Finally I found the answer. What the heck is that offset came from? plane.bytes doesn't have issue, but plane.bytes.buffer needs to be set offset.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `CameraImage` format for Android and iOS are different.

- Android: `ImageFormatGroup.yuv420`
- iOS: `ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888`

We need to handle them respectively.

### Android

Get **Y**, **U**, **V** from the planes:

```dart
CameraImage availableImage;
int imageWidth = availableImage.width;
int imageHeight = availableImage.height;
int imageStride = availableImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
List<Uint8List> planes = [];
for (int planeIndex = 0; planeIndex < 3; planeIndex++) {
          Uint8List buffer;
          int width;
          int height;
          if (planeIndex == 0) {
            width = availableImage.width;
            height = availableImage.height;
          } else {
            width = availableImage.width ~/ 2;
            height = availableImage.height ~/ 2;
          }

          buffer = Uint8List(width * height);

          int pixelStride = availableImage.planes[planeIndex].bytesPerPixel!;
          int rowStride = availableImage.planes[planeIndex].bytesPerRow;
          int index = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
              buffer[index++] = availableImage
                  .planes[planeIndex].bytes[i * rowStride + j * pixelStride];
            }
          }

          planes.add(buffer);
      
}
```

Convert YUV420 to RGBA8888:

```dart
Uint8List yuv420ToRgba8888(List<Uint8List> planes, int width, int height) {
  final yPlane = planes[0];
  final uPlane = planes[1];
  final vPlane = planes[2];

  final Uint8List rgbaBytes = Uint8List(width * height * 4);

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      final int yIndex = y * width + x;
      final int uvIndex = (y ~/ 2) * (width ~/ 2) + (x ~/ 2);

      final int yValue = yPlane[yIndex] & 0xFF;
      final int uValue = uPlane[uvIndex] & 0xFF;
      final int vValue = vPlane[uvIndex] & 0xFF;

      final int r = (yValue + 1.13983 * (vValue - 128)).round().clamp(0, 255);
      final int g =
          (yValue - 0.39465 * (uValue - 128) - 0.58060 * (vValue - 128))
              .round()
              .clamp(0, 255);
      final int b = (yValue + 2.03211 * (uValue - 128)).round().clamp(0, 255);

      final int rgbaIndex = yIndex * 4;
      rgbaBytes[rgbaIndex] = r.toUnsigned(8);
      rgbaBytes[rgbaIndex + 1] = g.toUnsigned(8);
      rgbaBytes[rgbaIndex + 2] = b.toUnsigned(8);
      rgbaBytes[rgbaIndex + 3] = 255; // Alpha value
    }
  }

  return rgbaBytes;
}

Uint8List data = yuv420ToRgba8888(planes, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

Create a **ui.Image** from RGBA8888:

```dart
Future<ui.Image> createImage(
    Uint8List buffer, int width, int height, ui.PixelFormat pixelFormat) {
  final Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();

  ui.decodeImageFromPixels(buffer, width, height, pixelFormat, (ui.Image img) {
    completer.complete(img);
  });

  return completer.future;
}

ui.Image image = await createImage(data, imageWidth, imageHeight, ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888)；
```

### iOS

Use the `planes[0].bytes` directly:

```dart
ui.Image image = await createImage(availableImage.planes[0].bytes, imageWidth, imageHeight, ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888)；
```

### Display ui.Image with CustomPainter

```dart
class ImagePainter extends CustomPainter {
  ImagePainter(this.image);
  ui.Image? image;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 5
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    if (image != null) {
      canvas.drawImage(image!, Offset.zero, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(ImagePainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image]

### Source Code

https://github.com/yushulx/flutter-camera-document-scanner/blob/main/lib/mobile_scanner_page.dart

Answer (score 0):

I found, sometimes planes[0] bytes per row is not same as width. In that case, you should do something like the code below.

```
  static image_lib.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
    final width = cameraImage.width;
    final height = cameraImage.height;

    final yRowStride = cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
    final uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
    final uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

    final image = image_lib.Image(width, height);

    for (var w = 0; w < width; w++) {
      for (var h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        final uvIndex =
            uvPixelStride * (w / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (h / 2).floor();
        final index = h * width + w;
        final yIndex = h * yRowStride + w;

        final y = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes[yIndex];
        final u = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
        final v = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];

        image.data[index] = yuv2rgb(y, u, v);
      }
    }
    return image;
  }

  static int yuv2rgb(int y, int u, int v) {
    // Convert yuv pixel to rgb
    var r = (y + v * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round();
    var g = (y - u * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - v * 93604 / 131072 + 91).round();
    var b = (y + u * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round();

    // Clipping RGB values to be inside boundaries [ 0 , 255 ]
    r = r.clamp(0, 255);
    g = g.clamp(0, 255);
    b = b.clamp(0, 255);

    return 0xff000000 |
        ((b << 16) & 0xff0000) |
        ((g << 8) & 0xff00) |
        (r & 0xff);
  }
```

Comment: Where to find ImageConverter class

Comment: what class do you mean?

Comment: ImageConverter.yuv2rgb <-- This function cannot find

Comment: @KingWu update my answer.