# Convert YUV420 to RGB flutter

Tags: flutter

```
const shift = (0xFF << 24);
Future<Image> convertYUV420toImageColor(CameraImage image) async {
      try {
        final int width = image.width;
        final int height = image.height;
        final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
        final int uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel;

        print("uvRowStride: " + uvRowStride.toString());
        print("uvPixelStride: " + uvPixelStride.toString());

        // imgLib -> Image package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image
        var img = imglib.Image(width, height); // Create Image buffer

        // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
        for(int x=0; x < width; x++) {
          for(int y=0; y < height; y++) {
            final int uvIndex = uvPixelStride * (x/2).floor() + uvRowStride*(y/2).floor();
            final int index = y * width + x;

            final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
            final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
            final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
            // Calculate pixel color
            int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
            int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 -vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91).round().clamp(0, 255);
            int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);     
            // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF 
            //           A   B   G   R
            img.data[index] = shift | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
          }
        }

        imglib.PngEncoder pngEncoder = new imglib.PngEncoder(level: 0, filter: 0);
        List<int> png = pngEncoder.encodeImage(img);
        muteYUVProcessing = false;
        return Image.memory(png);  
      } catch (e) {
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR:" + e.toString());
      }
      return null;
  }
```

I have been following this code snippet from [How to convert Camera Image to Image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603146/how-to-convert-camera-image-to-image-in-flutter) to convert YUV to RGB to send the images via WebSockets for ML prediction.
Although it works to convert, the resulting image is rotated 90 degrees and the performance is a little bit slow. How I can rotate it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace  `img.data[index] = shift | (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;`

with

```
if (img.boundsSafe(height-y, x)){ 
 img.setPixelRgba(height-y, x, r , g ,b ,shift); 
}
```

and replace `var img = imglib.Image(width, height);`

with

```
var img = imglib.Image(height, width);
```

Comment: Your advice is excellent. Combining the code in question with your answer produced an image that was not rotated 90 degrees. However, if we give the CameraController a value that is not ResolutionPreset.low, our image is broken. Can you solve this problem ?

Comment: I got colors following your solution but my image is rotated bottom-down. So if I make a selfie using phone front camera and it looks fine to me, after the conversion above I get a png where my head is up. How can I solve this problem ? I am really looking for a solution for these issue

Answer (score 0):

For IOS version, the CameraImage is returned as biplanar which has only two planes.

Quote from image_format_group.dart:

```
/// Multi-plane YUV 420 format.

/// This format is a generic YCbCr format, capable of describing any 4:2:0
/// chroma-subsampled planar or semiplanar buffer (but not fully interleaved),
/// with 8 bits per color sample.

/// On Android, this is `android.graphics.ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`. See
/// https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#YUV_420_888

/// On iOS, this is `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`. See
/// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers/kcvpixelformattype_420ypcbcr8biplanarvideorange?language=objc

yuv420
```

For my approach, I use dart:ffi and link to c++ for Android CameraImage following the tutorial [from here](https://medium.com/@hugand/capture-photos-from-camera-using-image-stream-with-flutter-e9af94bc2bee). The conversion between YUV420p and YUV420sp [can be found here](https://blog.csdn.net/u014485485/article/details/89709798). There is no complete code for the conversion yet, but neither any solution for IOS around the forum.