# How to turn cameraImage into ui.dart image with flutter newest version

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have been following this page to try turning cameraImage into a image object [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603146/how-to-convert-camera-image-to-image](https://stackoverflow.com)
But it seems like the extension it use has update, and this code doesnt work directly anymore, i have been trying to modify the code so that is usable again. Here is what i got

```
// import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

Future<Image?> convertImagetoUIImage(CameraImage image) async {
  try {
    final int width = image.width;
    final int height = image.height;
    imglib.Image img = imglib.Image(width: width, height: height);;
    if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) {
      img = _convertYUV420(image);
    } else if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888) {
      img = _convertBGRA8888(image);
    }

    Codec codec  = await instantiateImageCodec(imglib.encodePng(img));
    print("codec ok");
    FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    Image processImage = fi.image;
    return processImage;
  } catch (e) {
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR:" + e.toString());
  }
  return null;
}

// CameraImage BGRA8888 -> PNG
// Color
imglib.Image _convertBGRA8888(CameraImage image) {
  return imglib.Image.fromBytes(
    width: image.width,
    height: image.height,
    bytes: image.planes[0].bytes.buffer,
  );
}

// CameraImage YUV420_888 -> PNG -> Image (compresion:0, filter: none)
// Black
imglib.Image _convertYUV420(CameraImage image) {
  var img = imglib.Image(width: image.width, height: image.height); // Create Image buffer

  Plane plane = image.planes[0];
  const int shift = (0xFF << 24);

  // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
  for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
    for (int planeOffset = 0;
        planeOffset < image.height * image.width;
        planeOffset += image.width) {
      final pixelColor = plane.bytes[planeOffset + x];
      // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF
      //           A   B   G   R
      // Calculate pixel color
      var newVal = shift | (pixelColor << 16) | (pixelColor << 8) | pixelColor;

      img.setPixel(x, planeOffset, imglib.ColorRgb8(pixelColor << 16, pixelColor << 8, pixelColor));
    }
  }

  return img;
}
```

But the problem i am facing now is that, the image converted out is just a black screen, i am not sure the reason why it turns out to be wrong. Can anyone give me some clue on how to fix it?